# Grappelli Tinymce missing theme

Tags: python, django, tinymce

I an setting up tinymce, filebrowser, zinnia, and Grappelli for the first time. I think I have everything setup properly, but it seems that I am missing some files and I am not sure where I can find them. I am getting 400 errors on the following.

```
"GET /static/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/skins/grappelli/content.css HTTP/1.1" 404 
"GET /static/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/skins/grappelli/ui.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1832
"GET /static/tiny_mce/plugins/grappelli/editor_plugin.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1820
"GET /static/tiny_mce/plugins/grappelli_contextmenu/editor_plugin.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1856
```

For some reason the pip installed version of tiny_mce did not include these file.

UPDATE:

I now have the theme working, it was missing from my downloaded version for whatever reason. I am still getting 404's on

```
"GET /static/tiny_mce/plugins/grappelli/editor_plugin.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1820
"GET /static/tiny_mce/plugins/grappelli_contextmenu/editor_plugin.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1856
```

I don't seem to have any folder in the tinymce plugin folder called grappeli. I have ran the ./manage.py collectstatic and know all my files are in the proper location.

Thanks,
CG

Answer (score 1):

The grappelli skings for tinymce [come with grappelli](https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-grappelli/tree/master/grappelli/static/grappelli/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/skins). You also should load the js files for tinymce coming with grappelli, so tinymce will find the theme files relatively to the tinymce js.

You can achieve this by pointing `TINYMCE_JS_URL` in your `settings.py` file to the right url, eg. `TINYMCE_JS_URL = STATIC_URL +'grappelli/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js'`. Make sure to run `collectstatic` and that your static files settings are correct!

Comment: Thanks for the link, I copied over the files because I did not have the skin for what ever reason. I am still getting 404's on [15/Oct/2011 18:18:19] "GET /static/tiny_mce/plugins/grappelli/editor_plugin.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1820
[15/Oct/2011 18:18:19] "GET /static/tiny_mce/plugins/grappelli_contextmenu/editor_plugin.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1856 even with the js file setting you suggested. I am going to edit my above question with some settings I have to make things a bit more clear.

Comment: Did you try disabling `grappelli` & `grappelli_contextmenu` in your tinymce plugin settings?

Comment: No, I found all the files around the internet and installed the missing files. This has solved my 404 issue, now I am having an issue where the tinymce field will not save it's content. sigh, all I really want is an easy way to add inline images in a WYSIWYG editor.